# Macbook keeps restarting with "Possible Memory Corruption" Help!

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, kernel-panic

I've been getting this issue for the past few months. Apple won't look at it regardless of my apple care being good for the next year, since I have the operating system on a third party SSD. 
They suggested I purchase a new SSD as it might have been corrupted, and I did. I installed a clean opy of OSX El Capitan, yet the issues persist!

Here's the Panic Report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       76822D11-36A3-6969-DCE3-FC37F834750D

Wed May 11 10:53:27 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff80041b3f90): "Possible memory corruption: pmap_pv_remove(0xffffff801d709b80, 0x7e05000, 0x4000, 0x4000000, 0xffffff911084bb74, 0xfffffeacc2f18028): pv not on hash, head: 0xffffff80048ee6d0, 0xffffff8004000000"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.40.184/osfmk/i386/pmap_internal.h:845
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff911084ba30 : 0xffffff80040dab12 
0xffffff911084bab0 : 0xffffff80041b3f90 
0xffffff911084bba0 : 0xffffff80041b4c36 
0xffffff911084bc10 : 0xffffff8004160cc5 
0xffffff911084bd20 : 0xffffff800415626c 
0xffffff911084bd50 : 0xffffff80040fea41 
0xffffff911084bd90 : 0xffffff80040fe870 
0xffffff911084bdf0 : 0xffffff80041074c5 
0xffffff911084be30 : 0xffffff800410b96a 
0xffffff911084be60 : 0xffffff80040d54c9 
0xffffff911084bea0 : 0xffffff80041cec4e 
0xffffff911084bec0 : 0xffffff80041ec23f 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Unknown

Mac OS version:
15E65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4E7B4496-0B81-34E9-97AF-F316103B0839
Kernel slide:     0x0000000003e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8003f00000
System model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 62102503864
last loaded kext at 5935863406: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f8697b000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.21.18
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.7
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   274.7
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.GeForce   10.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.4
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.1.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.7
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.1
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.3
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro9,1, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0C, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.1f175
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3431554638424455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3431554638424455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.4f4 17685, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Crucial_CT512MX100SSD1, 512.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HGST HTS721010A9E630, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Ran Rember to test my Macbook Pro's RAM:

```
Memtest version 4.22 (64-bit)
Copyright (C) 2004 Charles Cazabon
Copyright (C) 2004-2008 Tony Scaminaci (Macintosh port)
Licensed under the GNU General Public License version 2 only

Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65) running in multiuser mode
Memory Page Size: 4096
System has 8 Intel core(s) with SSE
Requested memory: 4586MB (4808769536 bytes)
Available memory: 4586MB (4808769536 bytes)
Allocated memory: 4586MB (4808769536 bytes) at local address 0x0000000101000000
Attempting memory lock... locked successfully
Partitioning memory into 2 comparison buffers...
Buffer A: 2293MB (2404384768 bytes) starts at local address 0x0000000101000000
Buffer B: 2293MB (2404384768 bytes) starts at local address 0x0000000190500000

Running 1 test sequence... (CTRL-C to quit)

Test sequence 1 of 1:

Running tests on full 4586MB region...
  Stuck Address       :                 setting  1 of 16                ok
  Linear PRN          :    setting  1 of 16                ok
Running comparison tests using 2293MB buffers...
  Random Value        :    \ ok
  Compare XOR         :       ok
  Compare SUB         :       ok
  Compare MUL         :       ok
  Compare DIV         :       ok
  Compare OR          :       ok
  Compare AND         :       ok
  Sequential Increment:       ok
  Solid Bits          :                 setting  1 of 64

FAILURE! Data mismatch at local BUFA address 0x00000001285c90c0, BUFB address 0x00000001b7ac90c0
BUFA Data: 0x0000000008000000, BUFB Data: 0x0000000000000000

  Block Sequential    :                   setting   1 of 256
```

Comment: The very first thing to do is run Apple Hardware Test (AHT).  Hold down the D key while booting from a powered off state and power adapter connected. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257. Run the "Extended Tests"

Comment: @Allan is correct, you can also check your **System Diagnostic Reports** in `Console`.  You might be able to see what's causing this.

Comment: I added the RAM testing with Rember in the original post.. Currently running Apple Hardware Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first glance, it appears that your memory is going (or has gone) bad.

The way to fully diagnose it, is to remove all but one "stick" of memory from your MBP.  Rerun the memory diagnostic software and/or AHT and see if the error persists.  Make a note of the address where it fails.

Then, remove that stick, and replace with another and repeat the test.  Keep the failed memory sticks off to one side so you know which one failed.

If all fail in the same address, chances are it's your logic board.  If only one fails at a particular address, it's that module.  You'll have to replace it.

### Update:

(Given that it passed on the first go round after removing one of the modules)

I did some quick research on your particular Macbook Pro and according to [EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.6-15-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html), while you have an *official* limit of 8GB, you can actually install a max of 16GB.

[image]

Since you have the machine open now's a good opportunity to upgrade to the max because the prices are quite good.  I have reccomended this particular [memory kit](http://radnex.us/Kingston_8GB_PC3-12800_kit) to someone with your model Macbook just recently.

Comment: Okay, so AHT wasn't running as it was freezing up.. I did what you suggested, removed one stick of ram, and ran the diagnostic with only one inside.  Result: Passed test. I'm going to switch it and leave the one I believe might be bad to see if it'll fail the test.

Comment: Shitty crucial sticks it seems. Back to the 90s when this was common with "affordable" ram that didn't work.

Comment: Even the best memory can fail. That’s why the good third party vendors offer lifetime warranties so you can choose to use them over the cheapest source if you want to avoid paying for a RAM swap when it eventually fails.

Answer (score 0):

When rember repeatedly flags memory as failing, it might be time for a repair or swap of the memory if it’s removable.

That tool won’t always find a problem if you have a memory failure, but when it finds an error, it’s almost always right. So the false negative chances are low but the false positive chances are so close to zero that you should look to repair next instead of more testing.