# Apps crashes after Memory Upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I have MBP late 2011 that was 4GB RAM. So I upgraded it to 16GB. It boots fine and I can use with Firefox and some other apps, but when I try to use it with some apps (Android Studio and XCode) those apps sometimes works and sometimes crashes.

The OS itself runs fine, except of instability on some apps after upgrade

I'm not sure why but I read [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165#1) and it says maximum memory is 8GB. Anyone who can help shed light on this? I don't know what to ask better than this as I'm still confused with what is happening.

**Update**

After running Apple Hardware Test I got an error. I believe something is wrong with one (or all)  of memory modules. Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Start with running [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.  Also, please define your crash - is it a "spinning beach ball", a shutdown, a kernel panic or something different?  It helps to know what's happening so we can assist in diagnosis.

Comment: Thank you. Let me test. By crashing I mean app get abruptly closed and then the famous message "Android studio crashed..." dialog

Comment: @Allan, I have updated my question

Comment: Oh...and your Mac supports 16GB of RAM as per [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.4-13-late-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html) (It's a *very* reliable source).  Also, start looking in your syslog for crash reports (`/var/log/system.log`).

Comment: Let me check that too.

Comment: After testing Power+D it wanted to do internet recovery. I was scared that I had to shut down by pressing and holding power button and now it cannot get to login screen.

Comment: Updated my question. I think memory modules have issues.  Do you have any comments

Comment: It's *very* likely it's a module.  Now, to determine if it's actually the module(s) and/or memory slots and which one(s),   see this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237970/119271) for a short procedure on how to do it.